Databricks Unity Catalog Error: [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster. SQLSTATE: 56038
When I execute a Databricks SQL select statement (the query is far too long to post here) I get the error when we use DBR 14.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)
[UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster. SQLSTATE: 56038

However, if we use DBR 9.1 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)
We get the following error:
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Catalog namespace is not supported.

We're not getting the error with any of our other queries. Can someone suggest why we might be getting this error with just this query?

The errors you getting suggest that there are differences in catalog support between the two versions of Databricks (DBR 14.2 ML and DBR 9.1 LTS ML) you mentioned.

UC_NOT_ENABLED error in DBR 14.2 ML

This error occurs when Unity Catalog not enabled on the cluster.
The below are the steps  to enable UC:
Step 1: clicking "Update Workspace", toggle the "Enable Unity Catalog".
Step 2: Metastore drop down, choose the corresponding metastore that has assigned to this workspace
Step 3: Click "Update"
Reference:
Enable your workspace for Unity Catalog
Regarding Error in

SQL statement: AnalysisException: Catalog namespace is not supported.

This error occurs when the specific query you are executing uses a feature or syntax that is not compatible with the catalog namespace in DBR 9.1 LTS ML.
You can check
Set up and manage Unity Catalog
